# USB mouse isn't working on MY laptop

Tags: windows-7, mouse, acer-aspire

I have a Acer Aspire 5750, I had recently bought the HP X1000 Wired Mouse. The problem is that the mouse isn't working on this laptop, I had installed all the drivers and plugged the USB in all three of the laptop's ports. I know that the mouse isn't faulty since I tested the mouse on another laptop and there were no problems. When I plug the mouse into a USB port, the cursor just freezes because I have enabled "Disable when external USB pointing device plug in". Please help and solve this situation.

Answer (score -1):

Try [this](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-remove-old-unused-device-drivers-in-windows-7) and then if that doesnt work try [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/135077-windows-7-installation-transfer-new-computer.html). Your problem is with most likely your default windows drivers or how the drivers are called. I do remember you said you updated the drivers, the question is "does windows see an old device with a bad driver" instead of the one you are using. hope this helps.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ben, but the first option didn't work for me and the second option seems like a system restore, I will not be doing this since I don't have back-up on my laptop.

Comment: It is not a data wipe, everything stays on your laptop if you read the guide. Your windows files are the only thing reset, which is what you are having a problem with, windows files.